# Determine A or B from given value.

Tags: functions

This seems awkward to ask help on, but here I am.

I was originally given a value from 100 to 299.  A value within the range of 100-199 using ceiling functions would produce the value 1, and 200-299 the value 2.  Knowing these values I was able to determine that the parent ID of this value (or better said "The ID that everyone knows it as") is A (1) or B (2).  Recently there has been some changes and now it seems that this range has increased to 300-499.

Instead of having to modify code for each time this happens, is there a mathematical way to determine whether the parent ID is A or B if the target range is moving?  The target range always seems to be 200.

Comment: If I understand correctly, whenever the given value $V\le L+99$, the ID should be $A$, and when $V\gt L+99$ it should be $B$. Here, $L$ is the lower bound.

Comment: Yes but the lower (and upper) bounds seem to move.  It's the range that seems to be constant.  I suppose if the above is true, I could just take the 1st digit if the number and take the modulus of it to determine if it's odd or even.  If it's 0 its A and if its 1 it's B.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be edited to be the correct formatting so I apologize in advance.

I achieved my goal by essentially reducing the value to a number < 10, then taking the floor of that value (to ensure I'm returning an integer), and finally taking the modulus of that value to determine if its odd or even.  So far it works in both of the aforementioned scenarios.

```
Get_LayerId = function(guid)
    local function layerMath(n)
        local retStr
        local x = 0

        while n > 10 do
            n = n / 10
        end

        x = math.floor(n)

        if x % 2 ~= 0 then
            retStr = 'A'
            retInt = 1
        else
            retStr = 'B'
            retInt = 2
        end
        return retInt, retStr
    end

    if not IsInInstance() then
        if guid ~= nil then
            local type, zero, server_id, instance_id, zone_uid, npc_id, spawn_uid = strsplit("-",guid)
            if type == "Creature" then
                aura_env.zoneId = zone_uid
                layerNum, LayerLet = layerMath(tonumber(zone_uid))
            end
        end
    end
    return layerNum, LayerLet
end
```

Comment: Code should not be used.